# Following code in a constructor generates warning

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, constructor

```
    mutex_map[key] = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

mutex_map is of following type:

```
    static std::map<std::string, pthread_mutex_t> mutex_map;
```

in the same file at global scope

I am getting following warning for plain c++

```
    warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

I am not exactly able understand this warning & how to resolve this

Answer (score 4):

Your `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is equivalent in some way to an initializer list.

In C++03, you can initialize an array like this:

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Notice the initializer list. However, there is no support for classes to do that.

In C++11, they added `std::initializer_list<T>`, so this syntax is possible. Consider the following:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Or, even easier:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
```

That will work on C++11, but not C++03, because in C++11, the vector has a constructor that takes an initializer list argument. You can include this in your own classes as well. Note that the latter is equivalent to the following, as normal:

```
std::vector<int> v ({1,2,3,4,5});
```

This helps illustrate the point that the initializer list is an actual type now.

If you'd like to see Stroustrup's blurb, I point you to his [C++11 FAQ](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#init-list).

Comment: @clickstefan, I don't use it, so I don't know what `pthread_mutex_t` is exactly, but it most likely just has the initializer list syntax as a short way, and has a long way through other members of the class.

Answer (score 2):

For the following solution worked: You need to call

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_map[key], NULL);
```

instead of using `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

Comment: Good proposal, it's always better to use this in C++. The following warning was removed: "extended initializer lists only available with C++11".